# Bootstrap 4 navbar hamburger not displaying properly, it's off to side of screen on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have put together a website from a combination of bootstrap 4 templates and have noticed that on mobile devices the navbar isn’t displaying properly.
The navbar hamburger isn't on the screen until I scroll half way down the page. The top half of the page I have to scroll across to see the hamburger, but the bottom half it just pops onto the screen. I'm looking through the html and css files to find what defines this but I can't find anything... does anyone know where I should look?
I have attached some screenshots to show what I mean. edit- cant show images due to reputation level
The navbar also isn’t staying in a fixed position on mobile devices either. I've tried looking through the css and html to see what is affecting this but I can't see anything unusual, could there be some conflicting code somewhere?
Can someone help please?

```css
/* Mobile Navigation */
.mobile-nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow-y: auto;
  left: -260px;
  width: 260px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.mobile-nav * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.mobile-nav a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  color: #393f44;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.mobile-nav a:hover, .mobile-nav .active > a, .mobile-nav li:hover > a {
  color: #36b94c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.mobile-nav .drop-down > a:after {
  content: "\ea99";
  font-family: IcoFont;
  padding-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}

.mobile-nav .active.drop-down > a:after {
  content: "\eaa0";
}

.mobile-nav .drop-down > a {
  padding-right: 35px;
}

.mobile-nav .drop-down ul {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-nav .drop-down li {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 9998;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  outline: none !important;
  line-height: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: right;
}

.mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #5c768d;
}

.mobile-nav-overly {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9997;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(31, 53, 72, 0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.mobile-nav-active {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mobile-nav-active .mobile-nav {
  left: 0;
}

.mobile-nav-active .mobile-nav-toggle i {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="logo float-left">
        <!--<h1 class="text-light"><a href="index.html"><span></span></a></h1> -->
        <!-- Uncomment below if you prefer to use an image logo -->
        <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/img/Logo-top-bar2.png" alt="Integrative Clinical Nutrition Logo" width="300" height="55"></a>
      </div>

      <nav class="nav-menu float-right d-none d-lg-block">
        <ul>
          <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="services.html">Services</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="services.html#services">Services</a></li>             
              <li><a href="services.html#pricing">Pricing</a></li>
              <li><a href="services.html#private-health">Private Health Rebates</a></li>             
            </ul>
          </li>          
          <li class="drop-down"><a href="recipes.html">Recipes</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="recipes.html#recipes">Recipes</a></li>             
              <li><a href="recipes.html#videos">Videos</a></li>                           
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>          
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- .nav-menu -->

    </div>
  </header>
```

Comment: Your classes don't match your html? There is no reference to `mobile-nav` in your html? And no bootstrap 4 nav classes or hamburger button?

Comment: I actually have 2 css files as I've used multiple templates and put them together, I probably need to condense it down to one file...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem that was causing the white space at the side of the screen and pushing the hamburger off to the side, it was an animation I was using

data-aos="fade-left"

Once I changed this it works perfectly, I just changed it to data-aos="fade-up"